# Printing Array on Html with Angular

Tags: angular, html, angular7

I am working on Angular for the first time and i am trying to display some data. The data is in an array

[Me, Three, Four]

I am trying to loop through it to print out the data but it is not working. Currently, i am doing it this way

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="channel">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Channel </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.channel}} </td>
    </ng-container>
```

and what i am getting on the column is this

[Me, Three, Four]

```
channel: "[ME, WE, US]"
end: "2018-03-29T08:00:00Z"
states: "[NY, Non-NY]"
start: "2018-03-29T08:00:00Z"
trans: "[Act:Add]"
```

how do i remove the [] from the data? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="channel">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Channel </th>
    <td mat-cell *ngFor="let element of nameOfArray"> {{element}}</td>
 </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your array/json comeing like this

```
channel: "[ME, WE, US]"
end: "2018-03-29T08:00:00Z"
states: "[NY, Non-NY]"
start: "2018-03-29T08:00:00Z"
trans: "[Act:Add]"
```

than add html

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let element of nameOfArray">
            <th mat-header-cell> Channel </th> 
            <th mat-header-cell> end</th>
            <th mat-header-cell> states</th>
            <th mat-header-cell> start</th>
            <th mat-header-cell> trans</th>
          <td mat-cell >{{element.channel}}</td>
          <td mat-cell >{{element.end}}</td>
          <td mat-cell >{{element.states}}</td>
          <td mat-cell >{{element.start}}</td>
          <td mat-cell >{{element.trans}}</td>
 </ng-container>
```

if you want remove this

```
end: "2018-03-29T08:00:00Z"
```

than you can not get(access) in your rest
or can not rewrite in your html remove from above code.